why select options not updating after updating property?
data:() =>({
  selectedCity:0,
  cities: [{id:0, name: 'England'},{id:1, name: 'Germany'}],
})

before requests it works correctly.
let cityObj = Object.values(data).map(city => {
  return { id: parseInt(city.id), name: city.topic };
});
this.cities = [{id: 0, name: 'England' },...cityObj];

I am trying to update cities after a request from the server. in console.log it shows that cities is changed but in site no changes.
Without ref I couldn't get the selected value maybe it is because I am using VueJS via a CDN.
<select ref="mySelect" v-model="selectedCity">
  <option v-for="city in cities" :value="city.id" :id="city.id" :selected="city.id == selectedCity">{{ city.name }}</option>
</select>

I tried with the following this.$set(this.cities, index, cityObj);  but it is still not working.

Hm, quite confusing as it is right now. Could you please provide a [repro]?

You missed defining the key in your v-for to make option s. <options v-for="city in cities" :key="city.id"

@Raeisi this should not block the reactivity part of things.

@Raeisi unexpectedly it works if i use options instead of option but all styles are not working. Still didnt get why it is not working with option

Some weird bug, you can skip that one.

thank you all, will try to find out why it is not working with 'option'

Please provide a [repro] if you wish to have it fixed faster!

The options is a spelling mistake. The point is to use the key prop in loops: :key="city.id"
